# Openlayers javascript library in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, openlayers

we are working on a project using typescript. This is out first project with typescript.
In this project we need to connect to a WFS server and this returns GML to us. Now to parse GML, we think of using the OpenLayers javascript library. I know there is a DefinitelyTyped version of Openlayers, but the GML parsing isn't ready yet.

So we tried to the javascript files. But i think we are missing something, because we are getting an error: Openlayers is undifined.

This is our code:

```
module PP.Data {
    declare var OpenLayers: any;
    export class WebRequest {

        public GetGML(url: string): XMLDocument {
            var retour: XMLDocument;
            var _this = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                crossDomain: true,
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                dataType: 'xml'
            }).done(function (data) {
                var format = new OpenLayers.Format.GML();
                retour = format.read(data);
                });

            return retour;
        }
}
}
```

So the error starts when we try to create an instance of GML.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about typescript, but should you not refer to OpenLayers as any within the GetGML done function, as you have declared it outside?

Comment: Typescript is showing an error then.

Comment: Presumably, yes. It will be to do with context, this, etc, but I don't know enough about typescript to debug. The line var format = new OpenLayers.Format.GML(); is certainly fine on its own.

Answer (score 0):

> OpenLayers is undefined.

Make sure OpenLayers is included (e.g. using a script tag) *before* you try to use it from typescript

## Not related to error but noticed

You are effectively returning `undefined` here (as retour isn't assigned before its returned).

```
       .done(function (data) {
            var format = new OpenLayers.Format.GML();
                  retour = format.read(data);
            });

        return retour;
```

You should return the *promise* ie. the return value of the `.done` function OR have a callback. It needs to be async all the way down.

Comment: Correct. I have added the Openlayers.js to the html page. After the js, i added my files: <script src="Scripts/OpenLayers-2.10/OpenLayers.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/TypeScript/PP.Constants.js"></script>